# Windows and Linux dualboot (2 ssd's, Windows on a dynamic disk)

Tags: linux, dual-boot, pop-os

I am trying to make this setup, however i have some questions.

1. Can my Windows reside on a dynamic disk ? Since they are two separate drives, this should be possible ? I have heard horror stories that Linux and Windows can't reside on a same dynamic disk, but since these are two separate drives can Windows be installed on a dynamic disk?
2. How should i proceed to install, after my Windows install is safe, should i unplug the Windows drive and then start to install Linux just to be on the safe side? And if i do so how to make entries on the linux bootloader so it detects the windows and is able to dual boot? Planning to install Pop-Os.

Thanks for your replies, i am a linux n00b. Appreciate the help!

Comment: what is a "dynamic disk"? That's not a term I'm familiar with. Maybe it's something from the windows world?

Comment: Dynamic disk seen from LInux as SFS with MBR or LDM with gpt is a Windows proprietary work around for the old BIOS/MBR 4 primary partition limit. Not required with newer gpt, so is this an old BIOS install? All systems since 2012 are UEFI based.  See link to Ubuntu Forums also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/482768/changing-windows-dynamic-disk-partition-to-basic-partition-and-not-the-full-driv This is what Windows 7 users did: https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/26829-convert-dynamic-disk-basic-disk.html Dynamic also not recommended for Windows as it does not support all Windows features.